# error: implicit declaration of function 'create_proc_read_entry' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm trying to compile a kernel module on kernel 3.13 and I get this error:

```
error: implicit declaration of function 'create_proc_read_entry' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
```

I google it and did not found any response. Here is the part of the code which refers to this error:

```
#if (LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(2,6,24))
    proc = proc_net_create(KAODV_QUEUE_PROC_FS_NAME, 0, kaodv_queue_get_info);
#else
    proc = create_proc_read_entry(KAODV_QUEUE_PROC_FS_NAME, 0, init_net.proc_net, kaodv_queue_get_info, NULL);
#endif
    if (!proc) {
      printk(KERN_ERR "kaodv_queue: failed to create proc entry\n");
      return -1;
    }
```

Can I get help ? I really don't know what is wrong. It might be the kernel 3.13 which needs a patch. I read somewhere (on KERNEL 3.10) that the kernel needs patch. Can anyone show me where can I get the 3.13 kernel patch to eventually fix the problem. Thanks

Comment: The error is because you are not including explicitly the header that declares the function and the compiler is 'including' implicitily for you and this throws a warning. The flag '-Werror' is making the compiler treats the warning as an error.

Try adding:

`#include <linux/proc_fs.h>`

Comment: @braindf: We not make this an answer, as it is the answer.

Comment: Also: `create_proc_read_entry` is a deprecated function.

https://lkml.org/lkml/2013/4/11/215

Comment: possible duplicate of [implicit declaration of function 'create\_proc\_entry'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26808325/implicit-declaration-of-function-create-proc-entry)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error is because you are not including explicitly the header that declares the function and the compiler is 'including' implicitily for you and this throws a warning. The flag '-Werror' is making the compiler treats the warning as an error. Try adding:  `#include <linux/proc_fs.h>`

Also: `create_proc_read_entry` is a deprecated function.

Take a look at: https://lkml.org/lkml/2013/4/11/215

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, I have already  the #include <linux/proc_fs.h> in my header.  I'm going to check the deprecated function

Answer (score 4):

in Linux 3.9

```
static inline struct proc_dir_entry *create_proc_read_entry(const char *name,
                                                            umode_t mode, 
                                                            struct proc_dir_entry *base, 
                                                            read_proc_t *read_proc, 
                                                            void * data
                                                           ) { return NULL; }
```

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/proc_fs.h?v=3.9

in Linux 3.10

```
static inline struct proc_dir_entry *proc_create(const char *name, 
                                                 umode_t mode, 
                                                 struct proc_dir_entry *parent,
                                                 const struct file_operations *proc_fops
                                                )
```

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/proc_fs.h?v=3.10

So change `create_proc_read_entry()` to `proc_create()`, and change the 5 parameters to 4 parameters. It then works.

Answer (score 2):

In your linux version 3.13 **create_proc_read_entry** this method has been deleted,instead using **proc_create or proc_create_data**.You can use this API

```
struct proc_dir_entry *proc_create_data(const char *, umode_t,
                       struct proc_dir_entry *,
                       const struct file_operations *,
                       void *);

static inline struct proc_dir_entry *proc_create(
         const char *name, umode_t mode, struct proc_dir_entry *parent,
         const struct file_operations *proc_fops);
```