# implicit declaration of function 'create_proc_entry'

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I'm trying to use the create_proc_entry() function to create a directory under /proc. When I try to compile the code, I get the following error: implicit declaration of function 'create_proc_entry' .

These are the headers I have included in my .c file:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <linux/vmalloc.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
```

The kernel version on the machine I'm trying to compile for is: 3.10.33-g7954807-dirty

Am i missing any headers necessary to call this method? Or is the method deprecated in my version of the kernel?

Answer (score 24):

/proc filesystem has been refactored in 3.10, the function you are looking for has been removed, you should use the full featured `proc_create` function family. Note that the signatures are different.

3.10 version:
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/proc_fs.h?v=3.10

3.9 version:
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/proc_fs.h?v=3.9

You can find greater explanation of using full featured /proc functions in the book Linux Device Drivers 4, or, if you want shorter solution, check this link (https://github.com/jesstess/ldd4/blob/master/scull/main.c) where you can see how the `struct file_operations` has been used. You do not have to setup to all fields of the struct.

Comment: I see that a struct file_operations needs to be created in order to use proc_create. What is the nomenclature of creating a callback for the .write member?

Comment: @theNoobProgrammer I did edit the answer, hope it helps.

Comment: The method in this link seems to be overkill for my purposes. I am essentially trying to do this: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-proc/index.html .  I was able to run this from my host. The created directory (/proc/fortune) once mounted could be written into and read from.  But on the device I am developing for does not contain create_proc_entry() but has the proc_create(). I am simply trying to change the read/write call backs from the link to work with file_operation structs. I don't think I need to go full on with sequential file reads.